# Windows 7 unidentified network (or limited access) after hibernate

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, networking, hibernate

My windows 7 network will show limited access or unidentified network after coming up from hibernation.

In the office I normally use LAN connection, I turn-off my wireless card (DELL Latitude has on/off switch for the wireless card). When I back at home I will turn on the wireless card, but it will take about 15 seconds to detect my home WIFI and then show limited access. I will have to restart the notebook and it will be able to connect to my WIFI and internet.

The problem will be solved if I restart the notebook, but that defeats the purpose of hibernation doesn't it?

I have tried uninstalling the wireless card driver but still does not solve it. I also tried updating my network card driver but windows says I am using the latest driver. On support.dell.com also showing I am using the latest driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was most likely hardware problem. After contacting DELL they came and replaced the wireless card, now it seems to be working perfectly. Good support from DELL.

Answer (score 1):

If it is an Intel wired or wireless chip, go to Intel, they will have the latest drivers. Dell lags behind in updating their drivers sometimes. If it is not Intel you might look for other sources for the latest drivers.

http://downloadcenter.intel.com/default.aspx